# Google Maps API 3 - Show/ Hide markers depending on zoom level

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to show/hide some google map markers depending on the zoom level. I've had a look on here for the answers and while I've got a better idea of what I'm meant to be doing I haven't had any luck being able to implement it into my google map.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
var locations = [
    ['<div style="width: 170px;">Title1</div>', 50.794785, -1.116947, image],
    ['<div style="width: 190px;">Title2</div>', 50.797, -1.109, image],
    ['<div style="width: 120px;">Title3', 50.796928, -1.107119, '../images/map-pointer.png'],
    ['<div style="width: 150px;">Title4</div>', 50.794703, -1.117880, '../images/map-pointer.png']
];
/* Get the markers from the array */
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
        map: map,
        icon: locations[i][3],
        zIndex: 10
    }); 
    /* Open marker on mouseover */
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    })(marker, i));
}
/* Change markers on zoom */
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
var zoom = map.getZoom();

    if (zoom <= 15) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    } else {                           
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
});
```

The markers are plotting okay but the zoom function I'm trying to do doesn't seem to work at all - am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to save the markers in an array and iterate over them to show/hide them on the zoom event. You're only saving the last marker in your `marker` variable. You need a `markers` array. Also, you can use the `setVisible` method of the marker rather than using `setMap`.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
var markers = [];
var locations = [
    ['<div style="width: 170px;">Title1</div>', 50.794785, -1.116947, image],
    ['<div style="width: 190px;">Title2</div>', 50.797, -1.109, image],
    ['<div style="width: 120px;">Title3', 50.796928, -1.107119, '../images/map-pointer.png'],
    ['<div style="width: 150px;">Title4</div>', 50.794703, -1.117880, '../images/map-pointer.png']
];
/* Get the markers from the array */
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), 
        map: map,
        visible: true, // or false. Whatever you need.
        icon: locations[i][3],
        zIndex: 10
    }); 
    /* Open marker on mouseover */
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    })(marker, i));
    markers.push(marker); // save all markers
}

/* Change markers on zoom */
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    // iterate over markers and call setVisible
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(zoom <= 15);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I changed it so they would show when the zoom was  >=15 - the only problem is  when the map loads the icons are there until you zoom in/out. At first I want them hidden and then when the user zooms in they'll show up. Is there also a way to have certain icons show at different zooms? Or would I then have to use the marker clusterer?

Comment: You can use the clusterer. Or if you want to do it all yourself, you can have multiple marker arrays and adjust their visibility based on the zoom level :) I don't know how many markers (and marker groups) you're dealing with so it's hard to say which method will be best for you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) I only have 4 markers I want to show. Ideally if I'm able to I'd like two to be shown when the map is zoomed out and then when the map is zoomed in it will show all of them. To have two arrays would I have to have two var locations (eg. var locations1, var locations2)?

Also, it seems as if at the moment the markers are loaded and only when the user changes the zoom do they show/hide. Would I have to use an if function to determine it from the beginning if the markers should be shown?

Comment: Add a `visible: false` property to your marker options and the Marker will be invisible from the first moment. Check the [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) documentation. I updated the code I posted to add the `visible` option.